# Request Permission from Application class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions, android-applicationinfo

As per the new Android doc, In order to collect certain data, I need to request for permission. So I am doing this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    ...
    if (PermissionUtility.isPermitted(applicationContext, android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
        userNumber = getUserPhoneNumber();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                Constants.REQUEST_CODE_READ_SMS);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

The problem is I m doing it in my class which is `public class MyApplication extends Application{...}` so `activity` isn't available here. Is there a way to ask for permissions in this class  or a way around to pass an activity?

Comment: Paste the whole method, since the `requestPermissions` method requires an activity instead of context, you'll probably have to invoke that method from an activity in a `MyApplication.checkAndRequestPermissions(this, ...)` style.

Comment: try  `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) applicationContext,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                Constants.REQUEST_CODE_READ_SMS);`. not sure but hope it helps.

Comment: @UserJP `(Activity) applicationContext` doesn't work since there is no activityContext available here.

Comment: @Shark, I have edited the code. It's basically inside  `onCreate` where I collect bunch of information before proceeding.

Comment: if `context` is not available then use `getApplicationContext();`.  And what is the `applicationContext` in your code `PermissionUtility.isPermitted(applicationContext, android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)`

Comment: @userJP `applicationContext` is `getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way for you `request Permission` from `Application`. You always need an `activity` for it.

When `Application` called, no Activity is initialized.

You can refer to this answer that why we need an activity for request Permission:

[Android: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions requires activity and not context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097229/android-activitycompat-requestpermissions-requires-activity-and-not-context)