# How to grant permission in Application class Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, android-application-class

I want to grant camera permission for the application using my `Application` class in my Xamarin.Android project. But I cannot call

```
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, _mPerms, 1);
```

within my `Application` class since `this` should be an `Activity`. So how should I call this method?

Comment: I believe it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219056/request-permission-from-application-class Best
Krzysztof

Comment: @Randi If user grants the permission, the **ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Activity activity, string[] permissions, int requestCode)** method should be called. But if you call this method in Application class, the activity is null, about grant permission that you can take a look:[Permissions In Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows)

Comment: @KrzysztofKaźmierczak,  Thanks..

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thanks...